# Can't acces localhost python server on windows 10

Tags: python-3.x, linux, windows, localhost, webserver

I tried this command using the Linux subsystem and cmd: `python3 -m http.server 8080`
Got this as a response: `Serving HTTP on :: port 8080 (http://[::]:8080/)` ...

After this, when I try to access the server using google chrome, it says the page is not available.
It seems to me, that the default 0.0.0.0 address can't be seen therefore can't be accessed.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no such address, try to connect to 127.0.0.1, or localhost, both mean the same thing, loopback, this address.

The measage you see of listening on 0.0.0.0, means that it will accept all addresses.